# Can I automate the generation of an API client for Clockify?

Tags: swagger, openapi, clockify

I'm writing some PHP middleware to connect Clockify to Xero.

Both platforms provide granular REST APIs so I should be able move data between the two with relative ease.

Xero provides an API client for PHP and so I looked to see if Clockify did also but couldn't find anything.

Their documentation however looks like it was generated via Swagger / open api, this could easily be used to create a client lib for various languages.

I couldn't find the Swagger JSON anywhere online so reached out to their support team and got the following response:

> I can definitely see why connecting Clockify with Xero would be useful. Unfortunately, this exceeds our technical expertise as support reps.
>
> While we're not able to provide you the swagger file you can make a post on Stack Overflow (with tag Clockify) along with any details you need regarding this and someone from the development team can help you there as soon as possible.

So my question is, could you please make the Swagger file (or equivalent) which was used to generate the [API docs](https://clockify.me/developers-api) available so that writing client libs for any language can be automated?

Comment: (It's OK for development teams to point readers to Stack Overflow, but this is not a support mechanism for private teams. I've edited your question so that answers are welcome from anyone).

Comment: @halfer When I was posting it I wasn't sure whether it was okay or not, thanks for the edit and clarification.